# Is the idaperl plugin no longer developed?

Tags: perl, reverse-engineering, ida

I am a student studying reverse engineering
I mainly use C and Perl, and I think this is a good choice

However, python is still being developed for ida, but idaperl says development has been discontinued (github). I have two questions.

1. Has idaperl development stopped?
2. github supports ida 6.5. Can this be used informally in 7.0?

Answer (score 1):

The [repo README.md](https://github.com/nlitsme/idaperl) says it's been discontinued,

> note: I am not actively developping this plugin anymore, since i myself now mostly use idapython for scripting.

I have been looking for active forks, but there seems to be none. So your best bet might effectively to use IDAPython. It's anyone's guess whether this version supports 7.0, but you might want to downgrade to 6.5 if you effectively want to use that. There seem to be [some tools that support reverse engineering in CPAN](https://metacpan.org/search?q=%22reverse%20engineering%22); depending on what you want to do, one of them might be useful if you're keen on using Perl.